# doing a combobox in javafx reading from a csv file

Tags: javafx

So I am having some problems with adding a combobox in my java program using javafx. I have seen examples using java swing but nothing really for javafx. I need to do a combobox reading a csv file to give me a list of account numbers that are already saved in that file.

I need actual help with reading the csv file into the combobox. The csv file has account numbers, account type, how much money is in the Checking and Savings Account. In the combobox I just need to load the account numbers. I don't know how to do that so I really can't provide an example of what I have done because I just don't know how to load the account numbers into the combobox. I have never worked with javafx and it is really confusing to me.

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you post a code example?

Comment: What particular part of this are you stuck with? (Creating the combo box? Reading the CSV file? Putting the results of the CSV file int he combo box? Something else?) [Edit] your question to include an example of what you are trying to do and identify the part that isn't working. It may help to read the [help pages on asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), and you should also read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).